# Show another ui file on button click

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qt-signals

I have a button on my first Qt window. When the button is clicked, the current window's ui should get changed to that of a different ui file. Right now, when I click the button, a new window opens, but the old window is still open.
Is there a way to replace the current window's contents with different content? or is better to simply open another window and destroy the first window?

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    otherWindow = new OtherWindow();
    otherWindow->show();
}
```

Comment: That seems a little tedious. One way of achieving something similar would be to place the other window over the first. It all depends on your workflow. Faced with a similar problem - but many more options, I opted for a tagged dialog.

Comment: How about a stacked widget where you switch to additional widgets in the stack using a button?

Comment: It seems [QStackedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qstackedwidget.html) is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is theoretically possible to replace one UI with another.

You will need to follow the following steps:

1. Destroy all the child objects created by the first UI in the constructor
2. Create an instance of the new UI
3. Run `setupUi(this)` on the new UI

As I said, this is theoretical. It's is far from practical though because your UI classes will have to be derived from the same base class and all slots relating to your first UI might behave strangely if connected to your new UI.

What I could suggest is that you follow the [Model-View-Controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern. Here's one suggestion, others may have better ones.

1. Create a derived class of `QWidget` to function as your `Controller` class. Design all the signals and slots that will handle all the user events generated by the `View`.
2. Design the UI in QtDesigner and make this a private member of your `Controller` class. Let is build all the UI elements in the Controller class' constructor and then connect all the signals and slots. This will function as the `View` in the design pattern.
3. If you need some persistent data, either create a class or collection of classes to function as the `Model`, or pass one to your `Controller` class. Use this to set all values of child widgets in your `View` UI.
4. Pass the `Controller` QWidget to the `QMainWindow` function `setCentralWidget()` to set it as the UI that the user can see.
5. Repeat steps 1-4 for each different UI that you might need.
6. When you need to swap out UIs, just use the `setCentralWidget()` on `QMainWindow` to change to the appropriate UI.